# FND-CP-ESP: Child: exec:: No such file or directory error: Solving this without dos2unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am using SSH Tectia client.

I have created a symbolic link on my shell script command using :

```
ln -s $FND_TOP/bin/fndcpesr  /app/gl/PROD/prod/per/12.0.0/bin/MOVEFILE
```

Though this is creating a symbolic link.

```
I am getting a Error: FND-CP-ESP: Child: exec:: No such file or directory error
```

I know this error can be solved by `dos2unix`. But this command does not work in SSH Tectia. Is there any other cmmand to convert the shell script to unix ?

Comment: Can you apt-apt get or yum it? Can you install tools?

Answer (score 0):

This issue may happen if you edited the script in Windows and transfered it with some FTP tool with the wrong Transfer Type that should be ASCII in this case. If you are using Filezilla you can go to Transfer>Transfer Type and select ASCII before transferring

Answer (score 0):

You are right. This is happening as the file gets converted to DOS file format. Unix uses only line feed (LF) while DOS use both carriage return (CR) and line feed (LF) as termination characters.

This CR becomes Ctrl M in Unix/Linux. So when you try to execute the shell script, you get this error.

Best way to avoid this is while moving file from Windows to Unix system. Make sure you move it using FTP ASCII Mode. This makes sure that files are converted automatically as per operating system.

As I understand you do not have this command, so you follow below methods to remove this.

1. Use vi editor in binary mode and find and replace this character using below command.

   ```
   %s/^M//g
   ```
2. sed command

   ```
   sed -e "s/^M//g" source_file > dest_file
   ```
3. Use Perl

   ```
   $perl -pe 's/^M//g' source_file > dest_file
   ```
4. Use tr

   ```
   tr -d '\r' < source_file > dest_file
   ```